# jQuery autocomplete item click and event bubbling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, autocomplete, event-propagation

How can I get the link click to trigger a select?

**EDIT**: Im refering to why doesnt the line  $("a:contains('item2')").click(); trigger a autocomplete menu select?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.js"></script>
</head>

<script>

$(function() {

var menu = $('<div></div>')
    .attr('id', 'menu')
    .appendTo('body')
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0, 
        source: ['item1','item2'], 
        select: function(event, ui){
            alert('selected ' + ui.item.label);
        }
    })
    ;

$('<button></button>')
    .attr('id', 'open')
    .button({
        label: 'display menu'
        })
    .click(function() {
        menu.focus();
        menu.autocomplete("search", "");
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .height(30)
    ;

$('<button></button>')
    .click(function() {
        $("#open").click();
        $("a:contains('item2')").click();
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    ;

});

</script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what I see, your code is working correctly, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, the line $("a:contains('item2')").click(); doesnt trigger a selection of the autocomplete menu. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by an "unfortunate" choice in the autocomplete widget -- it doesn't know what item you're selecting unless you've previously "hovered" it to make it the active menu choice.

```
$('<button></button>')
  .click(function() {
    $("#open").click();
    $("a:contains('item2')").trigger('mouseover').trigger('click');
  })
  .appendTo('body');
```